Why is $f(x) = \frac{1}{x(|\ln x|+1)^2}\in\mathscr{L}^1$ but not $\mathscr{L}^p$ for $p>1$?

I am reading this post for an example of a function $f$ being integrable but $|f|^p$ is not integrable for $p>1$. But I couldn't see why
$$f(x)=\frac1{x(|\ln x|+1)^2},\quad x\in(0,1)$$
is an example. More precisely, I couldn't see why $|f|^p$ is not integrable for $p>1$. Could someone please explain it?
Also, is there a nice example for a function $f$ being in $\mathscr{L}^1(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ but not in $\mathscr{L}^p(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ for $p>1$ under general definition of integration (not Riemann integration)?


For every $p\in[1,\infty)$, letting $t=-\ln x$:
$$\int_0^1\frac1{x^p(|\ln x|+1)^{2p}}\,dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{(p-1)t}}{(t+1)^{2p}}\,dt.$$
If $p=1$, this integral converges. If $p>1$, it diverges since for $t$ large enough, $e^{(p-1)t}>(t+1)^{2p}$.

To show that $f\in \mathcal{L}^1$:
$$\int_{0}^1 \left|\frac{1}{x(|\ln(x)|+1)^2}\ \right| dx=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x(|\ln(x)|+1)^2}\ dx$$
Let's put $u=\ln(x)$, we get:
$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x(|\ln(x)|+1)^2}\ dx=\int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{1}{(|u|+1)^2}\ dx$$
which is a convergent integral.
To show that $f\notin \mathcal{L}^p$ with $p>1$:
Consider the $L^p$ norm for $p>1$. Then we have:
$$\int_{0}^1 \left|\frac{1}{x(|\ln(x)|+1)^2}\ \right|^p dx=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^p(|\ln(x)|+1)^{2p}}\ dx$$
Edit:
Using the substitution $u=-\ln(x)$ we obtain:
$$\int_{0}^\infty \frac{e^{(p-1)u}}{(|u|+1)^{2p}}\ du$$
Since $p>1$, for $u\to +\infty$, the exponential diverges to $+\infty$ much faster then the denominator and so the integral does not converge.
